# v-btn of v-dialog disappears when adding v-bind to attribute

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

With Vuetify, I created a dialog in which I want to bind placeholders of my different `v-text-field`.

```
<template>
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn text icon dark v-on="on" color="black">
          <v-icon>mdi-pencil-outline</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <span class="headline">Edit profile</span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-container>
            <v-row>
              <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                <v-text-field v-model="f_name" :label="getName()" required></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-container>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
      name: "edit_form_personal",
      data() {
          return {
            dialog: false,
            f_name: '',
            l_name: '',
            email: '',
            phone: ''
          }
      },
      methods: {
          getName() {
            return 'joe'
          }
      },
  }
</script>
```

I am using `getName()` to bind 'joe' inside my form. 
The issue is that when I change

`<v-text-field v-model="f_name" label="First Name" required></v-text-field>`

to :

`<v-text-field v-model="f_name" :label="getName()" required></v-text-field>`

the `<v-btn>` disappears as if the `v-dialog` was broken.

Comment: What is `v-label`? The `v-` prefix suggests it's a custom directive but I can't find any evidence it exists. The way you're using it also implies it isn't a directive. There's a `label` prop and a `label` slot. Did you mean one of those?

Comment: indeed. I changed it. My bad

Comment: So your real code is using `label`, not `v-label`, and still has this problem? You don't see any error messages in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the getName function from methods to computed property

see the working codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/xxxOJGq?editors=1010

```
<script>
  export default {
      name: "edit_form_personal",
      data() {
          return {
            dialog: false,
            f_name: '',
            l_name: '',
            email: '',
            phone: ''
          }
      },
      computed: {
          getName() {
            return 'joe'
          }
      },
  }

</script>
```

also use getName instead of getName() in text field and :label instead of :v-label

```
<v-text-field v-model="f_name" :label="getName" required></v-text-field>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this hasn't fixed the issue, the btn is still not there

Comment: Here is the working codepen https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/xxxOJGq?editors=1010

Comment: I can see. Thats strange